# HTML Appearing as Text in Oracle Apex when Highlighting Text in Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I have a requirement for the user to highlight text as blue in a text area.

The html is not being applied to the text area and is instead printed as text.

Has anyone encountered and overcome this?

Thank you.

This is the code that I am using:

```
function ModifySelection () {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("P85_30DAY");
        if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {
                // check whether some text is selected in the textarea
            if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
                //var newText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart) + 
                 //   "[start]" + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + "[end]" +
                  //  textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                  var opnSpan = '<span style="color:white;background-color:blue">';
                  var clseSpan = '</span>';
                  var begText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart);
                  var endText = textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                  var selText = opnSpan + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + clseSpan;

                //$("#P85_30DAY").html("<span>" + begText + "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'> " + selText + "</span>" + endText + "</span>"); //appears as text   
                // textarea.value = begText + selText + endText; //appears as text                    
                $("#P85_30DAY").val(begText + selText + endText); //appears as text


            }
        }
        else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
                // create a range from the current selection
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
                // check whether the selection is within the textarea
            var rangeParent = textRange.parentElement ();
            if (rangeParent === textarea) {
                textRange.text = "[start]" + textRange.text + "[end]";
            }
        }
    }
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onkeyup = ModifySelection;
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onmouseup = ModifySelection;
```

This is the html for the element I am trying to highlight text in:

```
<textarea name="p_t07" class="textarea" id="P85_30DAY" style="width: 587px; height: 600px; font-size: 130%; margin-top: -431px; margin-left: -1340px; position: relative;" contenteditable="true" maxlength="4000" rows="1" cols="80" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work folks.

Only one highlight selection can be made. I will keep working it but if anyone has any ideas for multiple highlight selection feel free to contribute.

```
    $("#P85_30DAY").attr("contenteditable","true");
$("#P85_30DAY").css("postition","absolute");
function ModifySelection () {
            var textarea = document.getElementById("P85_30DAY");
            if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {
                    // check whether some text is selected in the textarea
                if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
                    //var newText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart) + 
                     //   "[start]" + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + "[end]" +
                      //  textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                      var opnSpan = '<span style="color:white;background-color:blue">';
                      var clseSpan = '</span>';
                      var begText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart);
                      var endText = textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                     // var selText = opnSpan + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + clseSpan;
                      var selText = textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd);


                    //$("#P85_30DAY").html("<span>" + begText + "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'> " + selText + "</span>" + endText + "</span>"); //appears as text   
                    // textarea.value = begText + selText + endText; //appears as text                    
                   // $("#P85_30DAY").html(begText + $("<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'></span>").text(selText) + endText); appears as object
                      //$("#P85_30DAY").val(begText + $("p").wrapInner("<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'></span>") + endText); appears as object
                  $("#P85_30DAY").empty();  //works for one highlight
                  $("<span>" + begText + "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'>" + selText + "</span>" + endText + "</span>").appendTo("#P85_30DAY");



                }
            }
            else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
                    // create a range from the current selection
                var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
                    // check whether the selection is within the textarea
                var rangeParent = textRange.parentElement ();
                if (rangeParent === textarea) {
                    textRange.text = "[start]" + textRange.text + "[end]";
                }
            }
        }
//document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onkeyup = ModifySelection;
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onmouseup = ModifySelection;
```

Comment: Do you really have to support IE 9? Ouch!  What do you mean by "multiple highlight selection"?

Comment: If the text area contents were '12345' the requirement would be for 1, 3 and 5 to be highlighted but not 2 or 4.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I can hard code spans around 1,3,5. To do that dynamically is the tricky part. If html could be inserted using the index of the value that would do the trick. Maybe a variable or array that would store the values of selectionStart and selectionEnd? Then the values could be used to parse the string and insert the span.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a rabbit hole. :) What happens if someone selects something that overlaps existing spans or the inner part of an existing span?

Comment: The index of the value should not change since the html is not being added to the value of the element. In that case the new span should only be applied to the new selected text. So <span>, newSelText, <span>, oldSelText, </span>,</span>

Comment: But overlapping spans?

Comment: more like nested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207856/discussion-between-dan-mcghan-and-billybarbarian).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML inside of a `textarea`. It's an input field and will render anything inside of it as plain text.

Instead, have a look at [ContentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) which will allow you to render HTML inside of an editable element.